# What does one call the downward-moving escalator?

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology

Is there a more concise phrase for "downward-moving escalator"?

For example, if "deescalator" were the word, I might say, "I went up the escalator, shopped for a bit, then went down the deescalator."

Comment: Is anything wrong with *"the down escalator"*?

Comment: What does one call an elevator when it goes down?  It is still an "elevator".  For that matter, what do you call stairs (you can go up or down them).  If you have a pair of staircases, one designated up and one down, you might differentiate the "down" staircase.  But you would do it by adding a clarifying label, there isn't a different term.

Comment: @fixer1234 That's not what I'm getting at.

Comment: If you just want something shorter than "downward-moving", Peter Shor and Omar Rojo suggest the answers.

Comment: I've never heard anything other than "the down escalator".

Comment: Of course, if you don't mind strange looks you could always say "de-escalator".

Comment: @PeterShor I've never heard anyone call it the "down escalator" before.

Comment: [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=down+escalator%2Con+the+escalator%2C+descending+escalator&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdown%20escalator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20escalator%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdescending%20escalator%3B%2Cc0) shows it's relatively common.

Comment: Just a check, the problem about what to call an escalator going up has already been solved?

Comment: There's a book title "Up the Down Escalator."

Comment: The example offered in the new edit is not the best one for the purpose: it contains the word *down* which would make it unnecessary to use a special word for the escalator in question, as *escalator* would be sufficient. A better example would be something like: I am lost in an unfamiliar building and am trying to get out, so I approach somebody and ask 'Excuse me, where is the _____?' Incidentally, the question should explain why *the down escalator*, which has been suggested in the comments and would be readily understood, is not satisfactory for the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use "descending escalator"?